# save Load User Control Dynamic to viewstate

Tags: c#, user-controls, viewstate

i add user control dynamcly to the page and trying to save to viewstate
   when i triyed to save the placeholder to the view state i got this error
  " PlaceHolder is not mark as serializable."

here is my code

```
  Controls_PriceControl ctrl = (Controls_PriceControl)LoadControl("../Controls/PriceControl.ascx");
    plcPrices.Controls.Add(ctrl);

    ViewState["plcPrices"] = plcPrices;
```

can you assiset me with this issue ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't save your actual controls to the ViewState, but only th their state (usually the properties). Saving and loading control properties can often be done directly in the property declaration:

```
public class FooControl : Control
{
    public string Bar
    {
        get { return ViewState["Bar"] as string; }
        set { return ViewState["Bar"] = value; }
    }
}
```